# Cache Busting using Grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using grunt-cache-bust to add a hash to my css files and i'm trying to add this to my dist folder task. I'm trying to run this task at the end when it's copied files from my source folder to my dist folder etc.

However grunt-cache-bust does not trigger as it does not recognise this file as updated and does not run when it's part of of my build pipeline. I can only run it by itself and when it does this just generates the same hash value.

How can I use grunt-cache-bust or a grunt cache tool as part of my build pipeline.

```
cacheBust : {
        revProd: {
            options: {
                assets: ['assets/css/sau-main.min.css'],
                baseDir: 'dist',
                queryString: true,
                deleteOriginals: true,
                jsonOutput: false
            },
            src: ['dist/partials/head.php']
        }
    },
```

Dist Task

```
grunt.registerTask('dist', ['clean','cssmin','uglify:dist','copy:dist','cacheBust','processhtml:dist','php:dist','browserSync:dist', 'watch']);
```